# Plotting via GeoPandas but only one point shows. What's wrong with my code? Map and points are in same projection

Tags: python, csv, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I've been stuck at this for two weeks and have tried already solutions online. I am using Python 3.8.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'path')
df = pd.read_csv('emscPhilippines2008to2020.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
crs = "epsg:32651"
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
basemap = gpd.read_file('PH_provs.shp')
gdf.plot() # POINTS ONLY
gdf.plot(ax=basemap.plot(figsize=(17,15)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15);
```

Both are in EPSG:32651. Even if the CSV is imported in 4326, same result.

Result

[image]

Points only

[image]

Comment: The scales look very different between both plots, suggesting you still have problems regarding the spatial reference. Can you show us the output of `basemap.crs` and `gdf.crs`? Furthermore, would you be able to share a portion of you data for testing?

Comment: I already solved this by re-downloading the basemap shapefile. But idk why both layers do not align when both are in the same projection. @MarceloVilla-Piñeros

Comment: Can you show us an example of how they do not align or maybe point us to the original files? There's not much to do with the current information you have given.

Comment: The first figure shows they do not align despite being in the same projection. I think the problem is I used a basemapshapefile that has been used in a couple of work files and projects already. Idk if that "degrades" the CRS information but that's my hunch. The shp is from GADM philippines.

Comment: From the first figure I get the impression the files have a different spatial reference. Your points seem to be in WGS84 as they range between 4 and 20 in the y-axis and between 120 and 125 in the x-axis. However, the polygons coordinates range from 0 to 500k in the x-axis and from 0 to 2m in the y-axis! Of course your points are going to be in the lower left corner if you plot both things together.

Comment: What happens if you define `basemap` like: `basemap = gpd.read_file('PH_provs.shp').to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})`?